# SQL Persian search

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below query returns 40 records (representing the number of users whose name is recorded more than once):

```
select  
    ownername, ownerfamily, count (*) cnt  
into 
    #p
from 
    branchdataview 
where 
    trfcode in (1011, 1012, 1014) 
group by 
    ownername, ownerfamily
having 
    count(*) > 1

select * 
from #p 
where ownername like N'پروین' 
  and ownerfamily like N'افشار'  --count=2

select ownername, ownerfamily, trfcode, *
from branchdataview with (nolock)
where trfcode in (1011, 1012, 1014) 
  and ownername like N'پروین' 
  and ownerfamily like N'افشار'  --count=3
```

These 2 queries must return the same result, but it seems that پروین is not پروین!

I have similar problem with other names in #p

How can I solve the problem?

My final query is :

```
select  
    branchcode, t.OwnerName, t.OwnerFamily
from 
    branchdataview b with (nolock) 
right join 
    #p p on p.OwnerName =b.OwnerName and t.OwnerFamily = b.OwnerFamily
where 
    b.TrfCode in (1011, 1012, 1014) 
order by  
    t.OwnerName, t.OwnerFamily
```

but because of the problem I mentioned it returns 72 rows while is should return at least 80 rows.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: `but it seems that پروین is not پروین!` ... you are referring to the same Arabic word twice.  What do you mean by this?

Comment: I tested it, it seems that the values are indeed the same, so perhaps the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Isn't your query `select * from #p where ownername like N'پروین'  and ownerfamily like N'افشار'` supposed to return 1 record, since you have written this only once in the `#p` table? Why are you expecting 2 records?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. What results do you expect (and why), and what is the actual result?

Comment: it is  sql server 2014

Answer (score 0):

I made mistake. I wrote wrong queries. I meant below query return only one row 
i use sql server 2014.

```
select ownername,ownerfamily,trfcode,*
from branchdataview with (nolock)
where trfcode in (1011,1012,1014) and
ownername like N'رضا' and 
ownerfamily like N'کریمی'
```

while below return 2 rows for رضا کریمی

```
select  ownername,ownerfamily,count (*) cnt  
from branchdataview 
group by ownername,ownerfamily
having count(*)>1
```

it seems that one 'رضا کریمی' cant be recognised by first query.